# Dont understand why parentheses must be used in a Case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using a CASE statement in the general form

```
CASE 
WHEN A is NULL or B is NULL
THEN
```

However, a coworker has told me this is incorrect and that I should be using parentheses such as

```
CASE
WHEN (A is NULL or B is NULL)
THEN
```

I am not quite sure why the first approach is incorrect? Is it just a question of performance?

Comment: It is just more readable, result is the same.

Comment: Have your co-worker explain to you why they think it is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe co-worker said for OR and AND.

Comment: Your co-worker is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach isn't *incorrect*, the are used to group logic and order precedence. For instance, run this:

```
create table #temp (a int, b int)
insert into #temp (a, b) values
(1,1),
(2,null),
(null,3)

select 
   case when a is null or b is null then 'one is null' 
   else 'neither is null' 
   end as stmt 
from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

They are the exact same in this case.  Pun intended...

What your coworker is probably referring to is the handling of `OR` with `AND`.  SQL Server naturally gives `AND` precedence over `OR`, so parentheses are required to denote the precedence you want.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Col = A AND Col2 = B OR Col3 = C
```

Is executed like this without parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (Col = A AND Col2 = B) OR Col3 = C
```

So if you actually want `Col = A` for both, THEN `Col2 = B OR Col3 = C` you need parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Col = A AND (Col2 = B OR Col3 = C)
```